# Suggested tag deletion

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Why do we have the [plata](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plata) and [shabbat-food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-food) tags? Both seem unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done.

For future reference, you too can "delete" such a tag [assuming you have editing privileges]. Simply remove the tag from the single question they were on. [They will then be removed at midnight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101263/161519).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that!